# Using request to scrape a webpage does not return all the data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using the python requests package to scrape a webpage. This is the code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Configure Settings
url = "https://mangaabyss.com/read/"
comic = "the-god-of-pro-wrestling"

# Run Scraper
page = requests.get(url + comic + "/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

The url it uses is "https://mangaabyss.com/read/the-god-of-pro-wrestling/"
But in the output of soup, I only get the first div and no other child elements that are inside it.
This is the output I get:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="icon"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,viewport-fit=cover" name="viewport"/>
  <meta content="#250339" name="theme-color"/>
  <title>
   MANGA ABYSS
  </title>
  <script crossorigin="" src="/assets/index.f4dc01fb.js" type="module">
  </script>
  <link href="/assets/index.9b4eb8b4.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="manga-mobile-app">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The content that I want to scrape is way deep inside that div
I am looking to extract the number of chapters.
This is the selector for it:

```
#manga-mobile-app > div > div.comic-info-component > div.page-normal.with-margin > div.comic-deatil-box.tab-content.a-move-in-right > div.comic-episodes > div.episode-header.f-clear > div.f-left > span
```

Can anyone help me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: When I do `soup.find_all("div")` it only returns the first div and none of the others. I also tried to do `soup.find("span", class_="episode-title")` but that returns None. I'm not sure how to go around this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is loaded from external URL so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use `requests` module to simulate this call:

```py
import json
import requests

slug = "the-god-of-pro-wrestling"
url = "https://mangaabyss.com/circinus/Manga.Abyss.v1/ComicDetail?slug="

data = requests.get(url + slug).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for ch in data["data"]["chapters"]:
    print(
        ch["chapter_name"],
        "https://mangaabyss.com/read/{}/{}".format(slug, ch["chapter_slug"]),
    )
```

Prints:

```
...

Chapter 4 https://mangaabyss.com/read/the-god-of-pro-wrestling/chapter-4
Chapter 3 https://mangaabyss.com/read/the-god-of-pro-wrestling/chapter-3
Chapter 2 https://mangaabyss.com/read/the-god-of-pro-wrestling/chapter-2
Chapter 1 https://mangaabyss.com/read/the-god-of-pro-wrestling/chapter-1
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounds stupid but why is the url so weird. I'm new to this so don't quite understand that bit

Comment: @MCUxDaredevil When you open Chrome Developer Tools (or Firefox Developer Tools) -> Network Tab and refresh the page, you will see the URL there with the corresponding data.